# Bind ServerSocket to external IP

Tags: java, sockets

I've built a simple server/client chat application, for study purpose.
Now it works perfect locally while I initialize my server using the default constructor `ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(18524);` and on the client side I'm using `client = new Socket(servername, 18524)` while `servername = "localhost";`

I've also figured how to use it on my local network, i.e connecting to server hosted on 192.168.x.x.

Problem is when I try to bind my server to my external IP address, i.e 87.92.x.x

Any idea why this is hapening?

Edit: I've did the following, maybe I still am missing something.

```
server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("87.x.x.x", 18524));
```

I've also forwarded the port 18524 (TCP and UDP) on my router and made sure the port is open on my windows firewall.

Still I recieve: `Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind`

Comment: checked firewall configuration?

Comment: i think the firewall of your router blocks the requests to this port.
you need to forward them to your server

Comment: Not yet honestly, I'll check.

Comment: How is your server internet connection configurations ? is there a firewall / router on the server network ?

Comment: Try using the `client` on a computer that's not on your personal network. I once had trouble with my router who forbid any connection that came from within the network and was directed to the network external IP address. Also, check how you router forward incoming message on port 18524, and make sure they are directed to your computer.

Comment: Please look on the edit. Still no success. The address is complete, I use the x.x.x against nasty folks who might read this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind a socket to an external IP address. You can only bind it to an IP address that is local to the current host. Most usually you just specify 0.0.0.0. If the external port is forwarded correctly that is sufficient.

Comment: So if I bind it to 0.0.0.0, clients can use my external IP to connect to the hosted server?